# Python Cherrypy: 500 ValueError: Page handlers MUST return bytes

Tags: python, unicode, cherrypy

I'm getting the following error from my cherrypy script that is being generated by the submit module.

ValueError: Page handlers MUST return bytes. Use tools.encode if you wish to return unicode

I turned tool.encode on in my config but I'm still getting this error. I'm allowing users to upload content via the jQuery Form Plugin. Anythoughts as to why I'm getting this error?

Here is my cherrypy file:

```
class Root(object):    

@cherrypy.expose
def index(self)
    return open('/home/joestox/webapps/freelinreg_static/index.html')

@cherrypy.expose
def submit(self, myfile):

    cherrypy.session['myfile'] = myfile
    data_name = myfile.filename

    #Send back to JQuery with Ajax
    #Put in JSON form
    data_name= json.dumps(dict(title = data_name))
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

    return data_name



cherrypy.config.update({
    'tools.staticdir.debug': True,
    'log.screen': True,
    'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port': *****,
    'tools.sessions.on': True,
    'tools.encode.on': True,
    'tools.encode.encoding': 'utf-8',
})

config = {
}

cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), '/', config=config)
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head> 
            <script type='text/javascript' src='freelinreg_static/google.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='freelinreg_static/frontend.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='freelinreg_static/malsup.js'></script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <form id="dataform" action="submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myFile"/>
            <input type="submit" id="data_submit" value="Continue"/>
        </form>                          

        </body>
    </html>
```

jQuery (frontend.js):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function () {
        $('#dataform').ajaxForm({
            url: "submit",
            success: function (data) {
                var $a_var = data['title'];
                $('body').append($a_var);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rearrange global config update to happen after application mount:

```
config = {
}

cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), '/', config=config)

cherrypy.config.update({
    'tools.staticdir.debug': True,
    'log.screen': True,
    'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port': *****,
    'tools.sessions.on': True,
    'tools.encode.on': True,
    'tools.encode.encoding': 'utf-8'
})

cherrypy.engine.start()
```

Because you were calling config = {} after your config update command you were overriding the update settings for `Root` application.

Also, change your submit function to this:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out
def submit(self, myfile):
    cherrypy.session['myfile'] = myfile

    # Return dict, which will be autoconverted to JSON
    # by the json_out tool (see decorator above)
    return {'title': myfile.filename}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Makes a lot of sense! Unfortunately I'm still getting the same 500 ValueError.

Comment: It worked! Anyways to send the data back to jQuery as a JSON dict still? Now the jQuery doesn't seem to realize that its a JSON dict.

Comment: Yes, you should use... JSONobj = JSON.parse(data);  alert(JSONobj.title);

Comment: To return json from dict use json_out tool

Answer (score 9):

I my case the issue started after switching from python2 to python3.

It was resolved by setting

```
    'tools.encode.text_only': False
```

In the app global configuration.

Hope it helps

Comment: After looking at the other answers this is what worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Hi people looking for answers.
I had the same problem but in my case this little addition solved everything.

```
return <some-json>.encode('utf8')
```

Comment: Use json_out tool instead and just return a dict

Comment: @webKnjaZ well fixed my problem, I had the same error and these two words fixed it so I was happy

Comment: Yes, it's just not the best way to go architecturally.